# problem while using for loop in async function in node js es6

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, async-await

I have written this piece of code that retrieves a list of contacts and in response show a JSON everything works fine but the code doesn't show any output what should I have done? this is my code:

```
export const ContactListPost = (req, res) => {
        //const userHeader = req.get('userid');
        const contacts = req.body;
        console.log(contacts);
        let users = [];
        const delay = contact => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let sql = "select user.userid, user.fullname, user.phone, 

    photos.name as photo_link " +
                "from user left outer join photos on photos.uploader_id = user.userid where user.phone = ?";
            console.log("contact " + contact);
            con.query(sql, [contact], function (err, result) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else{
                    if (result.length > 0) {
                        users.push(result);
                        console.log(result);
                        resolve(result);
                    }else{
                        console.log("empty number");
                        //reject(result);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
        (async function loop() {
            for (let i = 0; i< contacts.length ; i++){
                let result = await delay(contacts[i].number);
                users.push(result);
                console.log("result " + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("i " + i);
            }
            console.log("users " + JSON.stringify(users));
            res.json(JSON.stringify(users));
        })();

    };
```

this piece of code doesn't show

console.log("users " + JSON.stringify(users));

res.json(JSON.stringify(users));
thanks for advice

Comment: Side note: Always resolve your promises, that is fulfilled or rejected. One of your paths doesn't resolve the promise.

Comment: Side note: Why are pushing the result to the user array `users.push(result);` if you are already resolving the promise with that value?

Answer (score 0):

> If the promise is rejected, the await expression throws the rejected value.

You need to handle rejected promises. If one of the calls to `delay` returns a rejected promise, the rejected value is thrown and the execution of the function will stop and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack.

[await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

[throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)